# Is there a better way to EXTEND a DATA class into multiple sub classes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, data-class

Let us suppose we have some data classes like following:

```
data class Order(
orderId: String,
payment: Payment,
customer: String,
...)

data class Payment(
total: BigDecimal,
date: ZoneDateTime,
...) 
{
fun getTotal() = total
}
```

I want to create new types of *Order*, let's say *OrderYellow* and *OrderBlue* to have different new custom fields and also has the possibility to re-override for example the `getTotal()` method of Payment data class

One way could be a "*Java*" oriented implementation

```
abstract class SuperOrder {
abstract val baseOrder: Order,
}

data class OrderYellow(
override var baseOrder: Order,
val status: String,
) : SuperOrder()

data class OrderBlue(
override var baseOrder: Order,
val createdBy: String,
) : SuperOrder()
```

In my application it is impossible to implement proper inheritance *from scratch*, since the usage of the *Order* class is too much spread all over the code base, making impossible a refactor in that sense, hence the above proposed solution seemed to be the best one for the sake of preserving as much existing code as I can.
I also used a lot of time the **copy** method to maintain *immutability* of the object and manage the updates on the fields during the completion of the order.

In fact this is a good solution, but in this way I still have the problem that I can't override the `getTotal()` method of the nested class.

Do you have some ideas? Are there better ways to do it in ***Kotlin*** oriented code?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't really get the remark about getTotal(), what's stopping you in eg. OrderYellow to just not call baseOrder.payment.getTotal(), but rather a class method yellowGetTotal().